# Mongo- Query two different collections on a field for the same value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections,

```
Users-
{
 _id:,
 name:"",
 company_id:"",
}

Companies-
{
  _id:,
  name:"",
}
```

Now i want to query all the companies for which either the company name matches the name  in companies collection or companies for which name matches in users collection.

Comment: Please have a look on  `$lookup` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vishal1132/fa955e72c1824b1e1e64d5ef5d354059
This query is working, but for each user that matches the condition, it is returning a separate array of companies. I need to return a single array of companies. @varman

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$group`

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Companies",
      let: {companyId: "$company_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$companyId" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$name", "Rockefeller" ]   }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "Company"      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Company: { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$Company", 0 ] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "companies": { "$push": "$Company" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VcXGDq6efOs)**